# Why this trigger is not inserting records in my table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, select, triggers

Here are my 3 tables.

```
Booking(Bookingid,date_of_booking,groupid,packageid,price)
Passenger(passengerid,groupid)
package(packageid,type)
```

Here is a function which will be called when trigger gets executed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COUNTPRICEFORTICKET3()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
DECLARE
MYID INTEGER;
MYPRICE DOUBLE PRECISION;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT INTO MYID FROM PASSENGER WHERE GROUPID=NEW.GROUPID 
GROUP BY GROUPID;
SELECT PRICE INTO MYPRICE FROM PACKAGE WHERE PACKAGEID=NEW.PACKAGEID;
NEW.PRICE:=MYPRICE * MYID;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER COUNTPRICE3 BEFORE INSERT ON BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE COUNTPRICEFORTICKET3();
```

The problem is that trigger is executed successfully but when I try to insert records to booking table using INSERT query like this, it does not insert record.

```
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES(NEXTVAL('BOOKSQ'),'26-SEP-2018',1201,700,NULL);
```

Comment: `RETURN NULL` abandones inserting. The function should return `NEW`.

Comment: yes is that, and I don't know why you are storing thoes values and never use it

Comment: i am using those 2 values to count price for Booking table

Comment: Oh.. Yeah.. Know I see the New.price assigment

Comment: changing Return null to Return new hasn't helped.

Comment: Thank You, It is solved.